# Extract all matching patterns from a line/file

Tags: regex, perl

Is there an easy way to extract all matching patterns from a line or file to an Perl array
without using loops?

Comment: Why don't you want to use loops?

Comment: There is bound to be a loop involved in doing this. All you can do is hide it in something like `map` or a global regular expression. It is a bizarre requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
my @matches = ($line =~ /pattern/g);
```

where $line would either be the line you're looking at or the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/g` in list context.

```
@matches = $lines =~ /.../gm
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, File::Slurp on CPAN is a short way to read in all of the lines of a file at once.

```
use File::Slurp;

my $text = read_file( 'filename' ) ;
```